# ProGet - Importing and Exporting Asset Directories

Tags: proget

I have a requirement to make an Asset Directory (or multiple directories) in ProGet portable, i.e. Export to a USB drive and stand up on another (disconnected) network. This is to enable DSC driven installations of MSIs on a temporary, disconnected network.

Ideally this should not require a significant time to setup (i.e. lets not upload 2GB of files into localhost over http).

I've been experimenting with mapping the USB contents into the ProGet container by mapping the source path as a volume into /var/proget/packages using the ProGet Docker images, but as there are no entries in the SQL database, the files don't display in the Asset Directory.

Is there a way to tell ProGet to rebuild it's asset directories entries in the database based on files on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no re-indexing capability at the moment, all packages must be uploaded via the HTTP API endpoints or via the web interface.

If you would like to submit this as a feature request, please refer to this guide: https://inedo.com/open/feature-requests

Comment: I managed to work around this by backing up the database and restoring through provisioning scripts when standing up the docker containers. Not ideal but it gets the job done :)